# Segmentation fault while assessing a vector of iterators to a list of strings

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have an error while trying to access a value in a vector of iterators to a list of strings. This is part of a complex code so I'll try to present only the relevant parts in here.
I've searched for problems similar to mine but I couldn't figure out what the problem is.

These are the declarations of my variables.

```
/// Vector of lists of files
std::vector <std::list <std::string> > filelist;

/// Vector with iterator for the list of files
std::vector <std::list <std::string>::iterator  > iterator;
```

This is how the vector of iterators is initialized (the function that includes this is called 2 times with i=0 and i=1 for different file directories):

```
iterator.push_back(filelist.at(i).begin());
```

This is where I try to access the string value pointed by the iterator and the seg fault occurs:

```
std::string path=*(iterator.at(i));
```

Is there another way to access the contents pointed by the iterator? 
Is there a problem if the string is empty?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Would you show us a minimal working (compile-able) code that reproduces your issue?

Comment: The bug is almost certainly somewhere in the code you think is irrelevant. If it is difficult to isolate a minimal complete example, that is strong evidence that your code is over-coupled.

Comment: My first suspicion is that the iterator you stored has become invalid. This could happen if you delete the particular element it refers to from the list, or if you modify `filelist` in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that some list is empty and applying the dereferencing operator to begin() causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: I was doing filelist.push_back(); at 2 different moments and in between I would call iterator.push_back(filelist.at(i).begin()). The second time I would do push_back on the list all the content would be reallocated, leaving the first iterator pointer pointing to the old memory spot.

Comment: @Edien Usually push_back results in reallocating memory if there is not used function reserve.